# Chef: 'search' not finding nodes by role on dev

Tags: chef

I'm working on spinning up a cluster of nodes. In `myrepo/cookbooks/mycookbook/.kitchen.yml` I have

```
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  roles_path: '../../roles'
  environments_path: '../../environments'
  data_bags_path: '../../data_bags'

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-12.04
    suites:
      - name: node01
        driver:
          vm_hostname: "node01.localhost"
        run_list:
          - role[genericnode]
        provisioner:
            client_rb:
                environment: development
```

In `myrepo/cookbooks/mycookbook/recipes/default.rb` I have

```
nodes = []
search(:node, 'role:genericnode').each do |node|
    nodes.push("http://#{node['ipaddress']}:8080")
end

node.default['mysetting'] = nodes.join(',')
```

In my development environment, though, search returns an empty list. Do I need more than the `.kitchen.yml` settings above to be able to access the ip addresses of the nodes in my network with the role `genericnode`?

Additional information:

Here's the role:

```
{
  "name": "genericnode",
  "description": "Generic Node",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "default_attributes": {

  },
  "override_attributes": {

  },
  "chef_type": "role",
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[apt::default]", "recipe[mycookbook::default]"
  ],
  "env_run_lists": {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789268/search-not-finding-nodes-by-role-on-dev), copying the answer for the record:

For search to work under chef_zero you'll need to provide a folder of node objects as JSON to be the data that gets searched. Search won't find the current node unless it is on the server (which it isn't unless you add it to that nodes/ folder.

The usual fix for this is to use both search as well as checking local values.

```
ips = []
search(:node, 'roles:genericnode').each do |n|
    ips << n['ipaddress']
end
if node['roles'].include?'(genericnode')
  ips |= [node['ipaddress']]
end

node.default['mysetting'] = ips.map{|ip| "http://#{ip}:8080"}.join(',')
```